# Plz tell which one is correct or more precise

Tags: word-usage

> 1.When should we come today?
>   2.At what time should we come today?

Which one is correct?
I want to know the exact time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask the second question:

> At what time should we come today?

or maybe:

> At what time are you expecting us today?

My reason for choosing the second question is that, when asking the first question there is a higher chance that you get an arbitrary answer like "come in the afternoon" or something like that, I am not saying that that with the second question you won't get an arbitrary answer but it is less likely, also if they do give an arbitrary answer you can always ask:

> I'm sorry but could you please provide us with a specific time

or something like that.